# BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received is not called in C++/CX

Tags: uwp, bluetooth, event-handling, delegates, c++-cx

C++ experts!
Now I am developing c++/CX UWP application to connect bluetooth device.
For this, I am going to use BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.
As you know, to scan devices, it is needed to call BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received event.
To do so, I declared function connecting to this event and called BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Start function. But BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received handler is not called. If anyone knows, please help me.
My application is for UWP.

```
Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher^ bleAdvertisementWatcher;
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    initApp();
}
void BluetoothConnector::MainPage::initApp()
{
    bleAdvertisementWatcher = ref new Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
    bleAdvertisementWatcher->ScanningMode = Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEScanningMode::Active;
    bleAdvertisementWatcher->Received += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher^, Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs^>(
        [](Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher^ watcher, Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs^ eventArgs) {//event delegate handler
            do_something;
        });
}
void BluetoothConnector::MainPage::Button_Click_Search(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    bleAdvertisementWatcher->Start();
}
```

As far as I know, if it calls BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Start, it starts to scan devices and receives devices information.
But received event function is never called. Please correct me.
Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to subscribe to **all** events even if you don't care about the others. Also, this isn't C++/WinRT. It's probably C++/CX, a Microsoft-specific extension.

Comment: Thanks for your correcting me, @IInspectable, Yes. You are right. it is C++/CX. I corrected it. I think BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher has 2 events on document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher?view=winrt-22000. Actually it is document for c#, but I think it is the same. So I subscribed stop event, but unfortunately, it doesn't give me desired result. received event still never called.

Comment: There is C# [Bluetooth advertisement sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement). Would you might testing Scenario 1 on your side to make sure if the Bluetooth function works correctly. And if this only happens in C++ or it doesn't in C# as well.